# Concatenate List of Dataframes and Include Original Dataframe Names as Keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key, concatenation

I have code that creates a list of dataframes with the same structure. My wish is to append all of these dataframes together but add a column to the new dataframe that identifies which dataframe the row originally came from.

I easily appended the list of dataframes with:

```
import pandas as pd
df_rosters = pd.concat(list_of_rosters)
```

However, I haven't been able to figure how to add a column with the original dataframe name or index. I've found a bunch of examples suggesting to use the `keys` argument; but each example has hardcoded keys. The size of my list is constantly changing so I need to figure out how to dynamically add in the keys.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In PyCharm, it allows me to "Copy Name" of each of the DataFrames in the list. But the names are just ['00', '01', ... 'n'], so any way to distinguish (index?) between them in the concatenated DataFrame is fine.

Comment: Something like `pd.concat({f'{i:02d}': d for i, d in enumerate(list_of_rosters)})`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but I'd like this column to persist when exporting (to CSV). The code you gave me shows the index column as something like "00/[index], 01/[index]...n[index]" in the IDE DataFrame viewer but then when I export it this column is not in the CSV.

Comment: `pd.concat(d.assign(df_name=f'{i:02d}') for i, d in enumerate(list_of_rosters))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) an indicator column to each DataFrame in the list. (Names can be zipped together with the list of DataFrames or created by something like `enumerate`):

With `enumerate`

```
pd.concat(d.assign(df_name=f'{i:02d}') for i, d in enumerate(list_of_rosters))

   0  1 df_name
0  4  7      00
1  7  1      00
2  9  5      00
0  8  1      01
1  1  8      01
2  2  6      01
```

Or with `zip`:

```
pd.concat(d.assign(df_name=name)
          for name, d in zip(['name1', 'name2'], list_of_rosters))

   0  1 df_name
0  4  7   name1
1  7  1   name1
2  9  5   name1
0  8  1   name2
1  1  8   name2
2  2  6   name2
```

---

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
list_of_rosters = [
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 2))),
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 2)))
]
```

`list_of_rosters`:

```
[   0  1
0  4  7
1  7  1
2  9  5,    
    0  1
0  8  1
1  1  8
2  2  6]
```